# Trying to insert a dictionary in a delta table with a "generated always" column

Tags: python, sql, dictionary, pyspark

I have the following dictionary

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, StringType
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time

max_val = 0

batch_data = [{"script_name": "data_ingeston", "script_version" : "v1.0"} , 
              {"script_name" : "create_data_objects", "script_version" : "v1.0"} , 
              {"script_name" : "data_validation", "script_version" : "v1.1"}]

for batch in batch_data:
  batch.update([("Insert_Tstp", datetime.now()), ("Batch_ID", max_val + 1)])
```

that I'm trying to insert into the following table:

```
create or replace table table_name
(
     Insert_ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ,
     Batch_ID INT NOT NULL ,
     Script_Name STRING NOT NUULL ,
     Script_Version STRING NOT NULL ,
     Insert_Tstp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
using delta
location 'path/to/table/location'
```

with the following code:

```
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame([Row(**variable) for variable in batch_data])


dataframe.write.insertInto("table_name", overwrite=True)
```

It produces the following error:

```
AnalysisException: Cannot write to 'spark_catalog.table_name', not enough data columns; target table has 5 column(s) but the inserted data has 4 column(s)
```

which makes sense as I did only provide 4 columns, but when I try to provide the fifth column I get a different error about how I can provide a value for an ALWAYS GENERATED column which makes sense.

Can someone provide some assistance on how to correctly insert this data?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your imports please?

Comment: When checking the doc, they say `It requires that the schema of the class:DataFrame is the same as the schema of the table.`. So, maybe, this method does not works with ALWAYS GENERATED in delta tables ...

Comment: Editted OP with imports